# Elasticsearch mapping, date field with null_value

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to have a mapping in Elasticsearch with null_value that equals to "now" in a field with type "date"? Something like this:

```
"mappings": {
  "doc": {
    "properties": {
      "last_updated": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
        "null_value": "now"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So when I search the last_updated field will be equal to the current time, if no value exists?

Comment: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/4718#

Comment: So it is possible, if I define a timestamp?

Comment: "_timestamp" is a pre-defined field. You just need to enable it, by default is disabled. And that github issue is against 1.4.0.Beta1, so in a non-GA version of ES.

Comment: Ok, so this will just add the timestamp when indexed, it will not check current time when searching?

Comment: _timestamp is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. You have to do it when indexing your documents, that's what i do.

from the documentation:

> When specifying the mapping for a string, numeric, boolean or date
>   field, you can also set a null_value which will be used whenever an
>   explicit null value is encountered. A field without a value will still
>   be excluded from the inverted index.
>
> When choosing a suitable null_value ensure that:
>
> - it matches the field’s type. You can’t use a string null_value in a field of type date
> - it is different from the normal values that the
>     field may contain, to avoid confusing real values with null values